# Python Selenium While Loop only opens browser at first

Tags: python, selenium

this two functions are used to generate me a proxy and open a browser URL using the new generated proxy, to test if it's working, however using the while loop it only opens me the browser at first time, the other time is like its always failing

```
def generateProxy(self):
    collector = proxyscrape.create_collector('default', 'socks5')  # Create a collector for http resources
    proxy = collector.get_proxy({'country': 'united states'})  # Retrieve a united states proxy
    proxy = proxy.host+":"+proxy.port
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if proxy != "NULL":
        chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + proxy)
        chrome_options.add_argument("--test-type")

    # Remover Visual Browser 
    #chrome_options.add_argument("headless") 
    # Mute Audio   
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://google.com")
    time.sleep(3)
    btn = driver.find_elements_by_tag_names('a')
    return proxy

def testProxy(self):
    result = None
    while result is None:
        try:
            print("[+] Testing a new proxy")
            result = self.generateProxy()
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            print("[+] Proxy is bad, trying another")
            time.sleep(2)
            pass    
    return result
```

Comment: Try closing the driver after you have used it `driver.close()`

Comment: @IainShelvington I already did, still does the same,  it continues the loop like it's failing, but it stills only open the browser at the first time

Comment: What is "it continues the loop like it's failing"?

Comment: @Sers It prints             print("[+] Testing a new proxy") and then print("[+] Proxy is bad, trying another"), however after the testing a new proxy it should open a new browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the recursive statement wasn't executed first is because of the following statement:

`Collect = proxyscrape.create_collector('default','socks5')`

As the for statement repeated, an error occurred because the `default` was already defined and defined again.

So I got the following error:

```
proxyscrape.errors.CollectorAlreadyDefinedError: default is already defined as a collector
```

So I did the syntax like this:

```
try:
    collector =proxyscrape.get_collector('default')
except proxyscrape.errors.CollectorNotFoundError:
    collector = proxyscrape.create_collector('default', 'socks5')
```

The full code is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import proxyscrape
import logging

def generateProxy():
    try:
        collector =proxyscrape.get_collector('default')
    except proxyscrape.errors.CollectorNotFoundError:
        collector = proxyscrape.create_collector('default', 'socks5')

    # Create a collector for http resources
    proxy = collector.get_proxy({'country': 'united states'})  # Retrieve a united states proxy
    proxy = proxy.host+":"+proxy.port
    print("proxy : " + proxy)
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if proxy != "NULL":
        chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + proxy)
        chrome_options.add_argument("--test-type")

    # Remover Visual Browser 
    #chrome_options.add_argument("headless") 
    # Mute Audio   
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://google.com")
    time.sleep(3)
    btn = driver.find_elements_by_tag_names('a')
    return proxy

def testProxy():
    result = None
    while result is None:
        try:
            print("[+] Testing a new proxy")
            result = generateProxy()
            time.sleep(2)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception("Something awful happened!")
            print("[+] Proxy is bad, trying another")
            time.sleep(2)
            pass    
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = testProxy()
    print(test)
```